# JSP Project Structure - Files Placement

Tags: java, file, jsp, netbeans

I am developing a JSP project in Netbeans. I am using some JSP files and some java files.
The project structure is the following:

```
root
-Web Pages
  --Jsp files
-Source Packages
  --myPacakge
    ---Java files
  --myIndex (it's a folder)
```

**So, my problem is: I want to refer to myIndex from a java file, that is placed in myPackage.**

I firstly assumed that the java files see the "Source Packages" as root.
So, I thaught the path to the index would be just **"myIndex"**, but through the debugger I found out that it is looking at ***C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.14\bin\myIndex'***

I then tried the following path: **"\myIndex"**, but it's now looking at ***"C:\myIndex"***

Could you please help me with that, how the right path to myIndex should be, or if I should place it somewhere ekse in the project ?

Comment: I used an absolute path and it works, however that's not a right solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

What you show is the structure of your source project. When you're running a deployed webapp, there is no source project anymore. Everything is bundled in a war file, containing JSP files, other web resources, class files under `WEB-INF/classes`, and jar files under `WEB-INF/lib`. If you want to access a file which is, in the generated war file, inside `WEB-INF/classes`, then you should access it using the classloader, using

```
InputStream in = SomeClassOfTheWebApp.class.getResourceAsStream("/myIndex/someFile.txt");
```

And if you plan to store something inside the `myIndex` directory, then forget about it: the war file is read-only. Configure some absolute directory on the file system, outside of the webapp, and use this absolute location to store new files. Don't use a relative location, because it would depend on where the server is physically located, how it's started, what's the current directory of its JVM is, etc. And if the server is moved, everything will break.

Comment: Great answer. It would be nice to add a couple of words on why the files outside the webapp should be referenced by an absolute path and how context path changes depending on the way the server is run.